# cloud_sql_proxy: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) to set up Django on Google App Engine.

When I try to connect to my mysql instance with the Cloud SQL Proxy by running the following command:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances="my-instance-connection-name"=tcp:3306
```

I get this message:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./cloud_sql_proxy: line 2: `<!DOCTYPE html>'
```

Before you ask, I am replacing the above placeholder with the appropriate connectionName value for my instance.

Any ideas about why this could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have downloaded some html page instead of a proxy binary, and your (presumably Linux?) system tries to execute it as a shell script.

Try to remove `./cloud_sql_proxy` file and re-download it again via `wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64` (or other appropriate command in ["Download SQL Proxy" section](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#install_the_sql_proxy) of the doc).

If that does not help, please look into the file for hints on what might have gone wrong. You can do it with `less` or some other pager/text editor: `less ./cloud_sql_proxy`

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I managed to download the Google 404 error page HTML. Have re-downloaded and working now. Thanks!